# How should you end a Spark job inside an if statement?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What is the recommended way to end a spark job inside a conditional statement?

I am doing validation on my data, and if false, I want to end the spark job gracefully.

Right now I have:

```
if (isValid(data)) {
    sparkSession.sparkContext.stop()
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkContext has been shutdown
```

Then it shows a stacktrace.

Is `sparkContext.stop()` not the proper way to end a spark job gracefully?

Comment: have you tried `sparkSession.close()` ?

Comment: @RobertoCongiu There doesn't seem to be a `close()` method for sparkSession.

Comment: I would use `sparkSession.stop()` (which is the same as `sqlContext.stop()`), so I guess you are doing the right thing. But it seems that you are stopping the spark session while a job is still running?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to say that you can't call `stop` in an `if` statement, but there is very little reason to do so and it is probably a mistake to do so. It seems implicit in your question that you may be attempting to open multiple Spark sessions.

The Spark session is intended to be left open for the life of the program - if you try to start two you will find that Spark throws an exception and prints some background including a JIRA ticket that discusses the topic to the logs.

If you wish to run multiple Spark tasks, you may submit them to the same context. One context can run multiple tasks at once.

Answer (score 0):

### Once you stop the SparkSession means, your SparkContext is killed on the JVM. sc is no longer active now.

So You can't call any sparkContext related objects/functions for creating RDD/Dataframe or anything else.
If you call the same sparksession again in the flow of program.. you should find the above Exception.
For example.

```
`    val rdd=sc.parallelize(Seq(Row("RAMA","DAS","25"),Row("smritu","ranjan","26")))
    val df=spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
    df.show()   //It works fine
    if(df.select("fname").collect()(0).getAs[String]("fname")=="MAA"){
    println("continue")
    }
    else{
    spark.stop()   //stopping sparkSession
    println("inside Stopiing condition")
    }
    println("code continues")
    val rdd1=sc.parallelize(Seq(Row("afdaf","DAS","56"),Row("sadfeafe","adsadaf","27")))
    //Throws Exception...
    val df1=spark.createDataFrame(rdd1,schema)
    df1.show()
`
```

Comment: So how should I end the application once I stop the `sparkContext`? Should I use`System.exit(1)`? Should I use a `return` statement?

Comment: Yes if you want to stop application you can use System.exit(1) inside the else block itself.